# Couting unique elements in python

Tags: python

I need a program which is couting unique elements in a list, but WITHOUT any built-in functions. I'm only allowed to use different lists and index of elements. 
So if theres a list: [1, 6, 7, 2, 1, 6], solution must be: 4.

Comment: more "let's have someone do my homework"?  hint:  len(dict)

Comment: The question wants to avoid built-in functions like `len()`.

Comment: no, len(dict) then, but surely not too difficult to use dict in another fashion, no?

Comment: It may be a "someone write this for me" question, but I don't think a recommendation to give up on programming is called for.

Comment: well, first of all, you showed no effort whatsoever in your original post, so, sorry, calling it as i see it.  second, if you are not allowed to use " in ", you didn't say so in your original post and now you have two answers which people took time filling in that you can't use.  and if you are allowed to use "index' then surely you can see that " in " is essentially syntaxical sugar for a call to index.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a second, empty list, use `for` to iterate over the items in your input list, check if they're in the new list, and if not then add them.  Each time you do so, increment a counter by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 6, 7, 2, 1, 6]
list2 = []
```

Simple solution using set:

```
print len(set(list1))
```

Solution using list:

```
for i in list1:
    if i not in list2:
        list2.append(i)
print len(list2)
```

without len function:

```
for i in list1:
    if i not in list2:
        list2.append(i)
count = 0
for i in list2:
    count += 1
print count
```

Comment: I also tried like this but using in or not in is not ok... So I wrote my version of function sorted to sort list from smallest to biggest element and than compare element i to element i+1 and when element i+1 is different than i, I append it in an empty list, then used len and thats it. But the Big O needs to be smaller :(

Comment: You can use for example heap. This will give the complexity of O(n log n).